# Meal planning app with grocery list and custom meal types

Tags: windows, web-apps, planning

I am looking for a meal planner application

**Features:**

- adding my own recipies
- defining meals for each week day, e.g., tom yam soup on Friday lunch
- generating grocery list from the ingredients defined meals
- defining meal types: breakfast, second breakfast, lunch, etc.

**Target platform**:
Windows or online

**Paid versions**: I am fine if the application is not free.

What would you recommend?

I have found [Paprika](https://www.paprikaapp.com), but version for Windows does not offer defining meal types.